# Why does boost::future continuation (.then()) work the way I wouldn't expect?

Tags: c++, boost, future

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "unistd.h"
#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 3
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
#include "boost/thread/future.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    using boost::future;

    boost::make_ready_future(3)
    .then([](future<int> a){return std::string("mu");})
    .then([](future<std::string> hi){
        std::cout << "mu1\n";
        auto ret =  (int)(5 + hi.get().size());
        std::cout << "mu2\n";
        return ret;
    })
    .then([](future<int> val){ std::cout << "khm: \n" << val.get() << " viii\n" << std::endl;})
    //.get()
    ;
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above emits the following:

```
mu1
mu2
khm:
```

If i uncomment the `.get()` at the end of the chain, I get:

```
mu1
mu2
khm:
7 viii
```

as I expected originally.

But why?
I'd expect that the lambdas passed as argument to `then()` are executed as soon as I have a result from the previous one. So it should work without the last `get()`.
On the other hand, if a final `get()` is needed to launch executing the chain, why does mu1/mu2/khm get printed without it?

Thanks for any insight you could provide!

Comment: I think the future is not executed directly and do the get will wait the thread like if you do the thread.join() (if you compiler choose to do a thread) Otherwise it could leave your function without the thread it executed yet. PS: I don't use the future every days so I am not 100% sure but I hope I could help you.

Comment: Thanks, it's a more clear, but still cloudy :)